# Interoperability with existing code

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Can you import existing chain code?

Can you use existing blockchain applications with a new business network?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot import or call existing Go chaincode from Javascript transaction processor functions.

You can migrate existing Protobufs to Composer models using this utility however:
https://github.com/fabric-composer/tools/tree/master/composer-protobuf